# Pagination codeigniter can't link page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I can add pagination, but from page 1 I can't link to page 2. The data on page 2 can't be shown.

My code:

```
$config['base_url']     =   base_url() . 'transaksi/index/';
$config['total_rows']   =   21;
$config['per_page']     =   10;
$config['uri_segment']  =   3;
$config['first_link']   =   'Awal';
$config['last_link']    =   'Akhir';
$config['next_link']    =   'Selanjutnya';
$config['prev_link']    =   'Sebelumnya';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$bc["paginator"]    =   $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('transaksidigor/bg_home',$bc);
```

In autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','pagination','form_validation','security');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `base_url()` which is missing index.php i guess. instead you should always use `site_url()`. this way either you have set index.php or not it will always send you to the page you are going.

```
$config['base_url']     =   site_url('transaksi/index');
$config['total_rows']   =   21;
$config['per_page']     =   10;
$config['uri_segment']  =   3;
$config['first_link']   =   'Awal';
$config['last_link']    =   'Akhir';
$config['next_link']    =   'Selanjutnya';
$config['prev_link']    =   'Sebelumnya';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$bc["paginator"]    =   $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('transaksidigor/bg_home',$bc);
```

Comment: can't .. i'am create link 1 2 selanjutnya but if i click page '2' or 'selanjutnya' data can't change, always 10 data in page 1... why?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

> $config['uri_segment']  =   3; to $config['uri_segment']  =  $this->uri->rsegment(3);